# check if values of an array is unique. if so randomize array

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have an array like this

```
0 => string '' (length=0)
1 => string 'nameMiddle' (length=10)
2 => string 'dsa' (length=3)
3 => string '' (length=0)
4 => string 'phoneFirst' (length=10)
5 => string 'addressStreet' (length=13)
6 => string 'addressCity' (length=11)
7 => string 'addressState' (length=12)
8 => string 'addressZip' (length=10)
9 => string 'status' (length=6)
10 => string 'gender' (length=6)
11 => string 'dateOfBirth' (length=11)
12 => string 'numberOfDependents' (length=18)
13 => string 'salary' (length=6)
14 => string 'startDate' (length=9)
15 => string 'ltdClass' (length=8)
16 => string 'deductionMedical' (length=16)
17 => string 'deductionDental' (length=15)
18 => string 'deductionVision' (length=15)
19 => string 'suppLyfCost' (length=11)
20 => string 'stdCost' (length=7)
21 => string 'effectiveDate' (length=13)
```

These values would eventually be keys using array_combine but I cannot have the same key on an array_combine. How can I check if the array has the same value if so how can I make the value unique into like this

```
0 => string '0'
3 => string '3'
```

thanks

Comment: You have 1 array and you want to user array_combine on it? And you want to make an empty string unique by making it the key? What if another element already has the value '0'?

Comment: "eventually would be keys"... of what use would an empty string be as a key? it's not exactly illegal, but given PHP's liberal typecasting/conversion rules, it wouldn't be particularly useful. e.g. `$x[null]` and `$x['']` are both the same key as far as PHP is concerned.

Comment: Hi this is actually headers from a CSV file.  Users may sometimes forget the headers or have the same headers in a column such as this one.  This is my code to make it easier to understand my question

`while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
            {
                if(!$header) {
                    $header = $row;
                }
                    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace values that are empty or not unique with their key, try:

```
foreach($array as $k => &$v) {
    if(empty($v) || count(array_search($v, $array)) > 1) {
        $v = $k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark as answered if this is it please.